# Place a static UILabel on top of a scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, xcode5

I have a typical Master-Detail layout with a UITableView in my MasterViewController.

In my XIB I placed a UILabel on top of the UITableView.

I intend to use this label to notify the user that his/her search criteria yielded no results and therefor the e are no rows within the table. And depending on the data I will show/hide this label.

I have a UIView as a container for both my UITableView and my UILabel.

Why, when I run my app, the label is nowhere to be found, and why, in the designer, when I click on my label (or on the table for that matter), and I click on Editor -> Arrange, are all the options grayed out?

[image: XCODE SCREENSHOT]

Regards!

Comment: Are your subviews in the right order? Front most is at the top of the list?

Comment: As you can see in the screen shot, my Table View is before my label, following your question I tried them the other way around without any success.

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController?

Comment: @mmackh Yes, my MasterViewController is a UITableViewController

Comment: @MatthysDuToit try using a UIViewController, you'll then be allowed to manually add subviews.

Comment: i m agree with @mmackh try to use `UIViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add subviews to a UITableViewController via the interface builder. You should try using a UIViewController instead. To replicate UITableViewControllers benefits, you can add the following to the - viewDidLoad method (and thus prevent jumpy UIRefreshControls, etc)

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[tableViewController setTableView:self.tableView];
```

EDIT:

This works 100%. The only explanation is that you're dragging the label into the TableView and not its superview. I've created a new application, here's what the hierarchy should look like:

[image]

Note how the Label is distinctly **in-line** and **below** the tableview? Here's what the simulator will output:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I changed my MasterViewController.h from UITableViewController to UIViewController, and fixed a single error it caused in my init, but unfortunately I'm still not seeing the label.

Comment: In your view did load method, try bringing your label to the front     ```[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.label];```

Comment: Still not seeing the label. I thought about trying it on a new project, but now I see XCode 5 forces me to use storyboards and I've never worked with StoryBoards before. I must be missing something simple...

Comment: Sviatoslav Yakymiv solved my problem by providing an alternative which I'm now implementing, however, my original question remains unanswered, if you have any other options for me to try and answer the original question, please let me know. Regards

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` has `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` properties.

You can resolve your issue in following way: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = label;`

Comment: True, but it wouldn't be always visible, i.e. it disappears on scrolling.

Comment: Thank you Sviatoslav Yakymiv, this does indeed work, it's not exactly waht I wanted (as mmackh mentions), but like I mentioned in my original question, this label only needs to be displayed when the table cannot present any data, a typical message will be "Your search yielded no results". However, I still want to understand why I cannot place static controls in my UIView on top of the UITableView.